# How to properly populate and render a model collection in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I have something like this in my code:

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp');

app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope, Todo) {
  $scope.todos = [];

  Todo.fetchTodos().then(function(todos) {
    $scope.todos = todos;
  });
});

app.service('Todo', function($http) {
  var fetchTodos = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/todo').then(function(res) {
      return res.data;
    })
  };

  return {
      fetchTodos: fetchTodos
  };
});
```

Inside my html template, I have two div tags with `ng-show` on whether `$scope.todos` is empty or not.

The problem with this is I'd see the unintended result for a split second before seeing the intended result.

Is there a common practice to have the transition of the view to be more pleasant?

Comment: Yo can use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) in `html` template.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at ng-cloak!